# Creating a Handle that guarantees hClose failure

Tags: haskell

I'd like to create a [`Handle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:Handle) that guarantees failure (exception) when it's passed into [`hClose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hClose). I need this for testing purposes.

How do I create such a `Handle`?

Comment: You can pass an `undefined` handle...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Unless you need to do something with the handle that succeeds before trying to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [`GHC.IO.Handle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html) of the *base* package has the function [`mkFileHandle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:mkFileHandle):

> mkFileHandle :: (IODevice dev, BufferedIO dev, Typeable dev) => dev   -> FilePath -> IOMode -> Maybe TextEncoding -> NewlineMode  -> IO Handle

[`IODevice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Device.html#t:IODevice) and [`BufferedIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-BufferedIO.html#t:BufferedIO) are typeclasses that provide basic handle operations for a device. In particular, `IODevice` has the [`close`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Device.html#v:close) method.

You can create your own dummy device type, define those two instances for it (with a `close` that throws an exception) and then use `mkFileHandle` to obtain a useable `Handle`.

See the code of the [knob](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/knob) package for an example of how to do this.